# Polling file for changes with readline() works on macOS but not Debian 9

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, debian, eof

I want to "poll" a file for changes.

Following code works fine on macOS 10.15.7 with Python 3.8.6, but not on Debian 9 with Python 3.7.3. On Debian when I add a new line to the to be pooled file it's not getting recognized and keeps printing check..

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
 
wait = 1
    with open('file.log') as fp:
        exit_pooling = False
        while not exit_pooling:
            print("*** check " + str(datetime.now()))
            line = fp.readline()

            if not line:
                sleep(wait)
                continue
            else:
                print('process line')
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does "pooling" a file mean? Did you mean "polling"?

Comment: Currently there is no mechanism in your code to exit the loop. `exit_pooling` will remain continuously False.

Comment: May be you should upgrade your python in Debian first.

Comment: I meant polling, my bad. Script will run continuously, exit_pooling as a variable is just used to have better control during the loop in case it should be terminated later on for some reason. I can't update Python on Debian 9 as there are no backports available (it's a managed server, so hoster prefers not to build by source)

Answer (score 0):

Worked as expected at Ubuntu18.04 with Python3.6:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

wait = 1
with Path('file.log').open() as fp:
    exit_pooling = False
    while not exit_pooling:
        print("*** check " + str(datetime.now()))
        line = fp.readline()
        if not line:
            sleep(wait)
        else:
            print(f'process line: {line}')
            exit_pooling = line.strip() == 'exit'
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm stuck on Python 3.7 on the server for now I would need a version without using the walrus operator. My main question is how come that the readline() behavior is different from macOS to Debian. That the polling mechanism on Debian doesn't recognize the change when I add a new line to the file for testing

Comment: I just tried your edited answer. It does print the content of the file.log. But while I keep the script running, so that it prints a  "check...." every second, and open the file.log and add a new line the script just keeps printing "check" instead of printing out the added new line. This expected behavior works on my local machine (macOS) but not on Debian 9